# Get index where the element matches using lightweight stream API stream

Tags: java, loops, indexing, stream, lightweight-stream-api

I have the following stream and I am using this [library](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) for streams:

```
String itemDescValue = Stream.of(dtaArr).filter(e ->
                 e.getRateUID().equals(rateUID))
                .map(myObject::getItemDesc)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

I would like to run a stream to get the index on when the value matches. I know I can achieve it using a simple for loop:

```
for(int i=0 ;i < dtaArr.size(); i++)
        {
            if(dtaArr.get(i).getItemDesc().equals(itemDescValue)){
            //do stuff here
        }
}
```

How would I get the index on when the value matches using the lightweight stream API.

Comment: You [ask about pre-Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243377/get-index-where-the-element-matches-using-lightweight-stream-api-stream/63243498#comment111833634_63243498), but use a method reference (`myObject::getItemDesc`). Are you using Java 8+ or not?

Comment: @AndyTurner no.

Comment: how are you using a method reference then?

Comment: This is a form of "zip" operation (in scala it would be `zipWithIndex`). Java doesn't do it well, but there are some libraries that can help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip

Answer (score 1):

Use `IntStream.range`:

```
OptionalInt idx =
    IntStream.range(0, dtaArr.size())
        .filter(i -> dta.get(i).getRateUID().equals(rateUID))
        .findFirst();
```

Comment: this is for java 8? anything for lower java versions?

Comment: there is no stream in lower java versions

Comment: @RUAROThibault yes there is its a 3rd party library - https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API

Comment: Oh I see :) My bad.

Comment: @xyz16179 you should make it more clear in your question that "lightweight stream API" is a specific library, rather than just "some easy thing with streams".